# Brief: Some game objects move, some don’t

Tags: java, inheritance, aggregation

I'm building a basic game from a brief, and have been given some code to look at. All characters in the game are game objects, some are moveable ones, and some aren't. The moveable ones have a position and direction.

I have been given a MoveableObject class (below). Moveable GameObjects instantiate this class in their own constructor. I have not been guaranteed this code is right, so I'm trying to grasp the theory behind it.

```
public class MoveableObject {
    int speed;
    String direction;

    public MoveableObject(){
        speed = 0;
        direction = "unknown";
    }

    public MoveableObject(int iSpeed, String sDirection){
        speed = iSpeed;
        direction = sDirection;
    }
```

and all the moveable characters create an instance of this class in a constructor.  For example, from a vampire class.

```
public class Vampire
    public Vampire(){
            MoveableObject thisObject = new MoveableObject(30, "South-East");
        }
}
```

To my knowledge, this is known as aggregation. I thought this was to be used in a HAS-A relationship, and not an IS-A. Since a character IS-A moveable object, should I not use inheritance or an interface? I also don't understand why you need to create an instance of a MoveableObject, if each character either is or isn't moveable, surely, you should give them the ability to be moveable or not (through inheritance or interface) and then instantiate the character?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that the Vampire class (or other movable objects) is planned to inherit from another class later on? (I guess this is from some sort of class assignment, right?)

Comment: Yes it's a class assignment. Vampire will inherit from a HeadVampire who in turn inherits from a GameObject. HeadVampires can appear and disappear, so they aren't MoveableObjects as such because they don't have a speed or direction, just a new position.

Comment: There you go. Java does not support multiple inheritance of classes, that's why. I.e.: You cannot `extend` two different classes. So if the Vampire will extend HeadVampire, it cannot extend anything else.

Comment: I understand that, but why use aggregation and not an interface? Surely an interface is better suited here?

Comment: That's a different question. I guess @giorashc is right, when he suspects a poor naming for a .. let's call it "State-Object".

Comment: do you have any interface that defines game characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends if the `MoveableObject` class also takes care of the actual movement of the object (i.e. update its position according to the `speed` and `direction` members) or just holds the `speed` and `direction` members so that the engine module of the game will use it to calculate the object's position.

In the latter case I would change the name of the `MoveableObject` class to something more appropriate and stick with the aggregation. Otherwise an inheritance will be more appropriate for movable objects. That way the moving logic will be implemented once and the sub classes can take care only for their own specific need.

To explain further if the `MoveableObject` is just a data container you can create an interface :

```
public Interface Moveable {
   public MoveableObject getMovementData();
}
```

and each moveable class will look like :

```
public class Vampire implements Moveable {
  .
  .
  private MoveableObject movementData; //
  .
  .
  public MoveableObject getMovementData() {
      return movementData;
  }
}
```

and in your game engine hold an array of all moving objects (Type moveable) and in the update method get the movement data and process it:

```
public Class GameEngine {
   .
   .
   private ArrayList<Moveable> movableObjects = .....
   .
   .

   public void gameUpdate() {
       for (Moveable moveableObj : movableObjects) {
           MoveableObject movementData = moveableObj.getMovementData();
           // Process and update as required using the given data
       }
}
```

Comment: No, the MoveableObject doesn't take care of the actual movement, it just holds the speed and direction. Thanks for the explanation, I thought an interface might be better.

I still don't quite understand why you would stick with aggregation if MoveableObject calculated the new position. Would it not make sense to keep the interface and have for example a calcualteNewPosition() in the interface?

Comment: Because if the MoveableObject just holds the data and does not perform any logic on it then it is just a data container and more elegant to store in a class where it is relevant to (since it has only two members you don't really need it but for many members this will be more easy to manage)

Comment: You can also of course create a Moveable class with these members and the Vampire class could inherit this class and use its members but this is prone to multiple inheritence in case you have more types of classes shared by your world entities

Comment: @Killian I have added a more details explanation to the answer if you still need it